# I need a copy of PACC/src/config.hpp for OpenBeagle

Tags: c++

I am trying to set up OpenBeagle for genetic programming and I says I need an installation of PACC but the site is down. I found it on SourceForge but config.hpp has been renamed to config.hpp.in and filled with Cmake stuff even though it is in the "src" folder. This would lead me to believe that there is an original version of it that I do not have. Seeing as I need to build OpenBeagle I would be very happy if someone would donate their version.

Answer (score 0):

When I compiled PACC the config.hpp file was created in the include/PACC folder of the solution directory. Just drag it to your PACC source Directory.